# how to concatenate multiple 2d arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation, multidimensional-array

hey guys i want to concatenate multiple 2d arrays in c this what happens when i just do two, but if i do more its sume together.it seems like every cycle it bushes one up:

**array 1**

```
222222222222222222222
000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000
111111111111111111111
```

**array 2**

```
222222222222222222222
000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000
000000000000000000000
000000000001000000000
111111111111111111111
```

**what i want**

```
222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
000000000001000000000000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000000000000000000000000
000000000001000000000000000000001000000000
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

**what i get**

```
222222222222222222222000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000000000000000000000000
000000000001000000000000000000001000000000
000000000001000000000000111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

function to concatenate

```
 #define map_height 6
 #define map_length 21
 #define map_stage_length 5

char ** concatenate(){
    char **array=create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length*map_stage_length); 
    char **mapsarray[5]={create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length),
                        create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length),
                        create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length),
                        create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length),
                        create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length)}; 

int i=0,j=0,n=0;

mapsarray[0]=load_map("./resources/maps/map1.map");
mapsarray[1]=load_map("./resources/maps/map2.map");
mapsarray[2]=load_map("./resources/maps/map2.map");
mapsarray[3]=load_map("./resources/maps/map2.map");
mapsarray[4]=load_map("./resources/maps/map2.map");

for (i = 0; i < map_height; i++)
{
    for (n = 0; n < map_stage_length; n++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < map_length; j++)
        {

            array[i][(n*map_length)+j]=mapsarray[n][i][j];
        }

    }

}

return array;   
  }
```

du you have any ideas why it pushes up?

Comment: Hint: `realloc()` doesn't happen automagically.

Comment: hey what does realloc() du exactly?

Comment: Why does he need to realloc? He has 5 2d arrays and one of the length of all 5 together.

Comment: I assume the allocation of memory is done in create2DCharArray. So there is no need to realloc at all or im missing something.

Comment: @fork yes no need of `realloc()` his mistake is in for loop

Comment: i think you can actually just use memcpy for that. No need of for loops.

Comment: @user2019104 I feel you code should run fine. You may have error any where else. Are you checking your `mapsarray` array , also check memory allocation unit `create2DCharArray()`

Comment: @H2CO3 I think he has not shown code that is actually error prompt? Do you think this loop will cause any error? I believe no .

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The functions return pointers and then those pointers are used as arrays. From this I deduced that dynamic memory allocation is being used, presumably realized with the aid of `malloc()`. (If not, then static or global arrays are used - in this case, it's not possible to resize them.) Then OP seemingly tries to extend the array beyond its original size, without allocating more space/memory for it. That's what `realloc()` would have come handy for.

Answer (score 1):

Do try this loop.

```
for(i=0; i<map_stage_length; i++){ // for each 2d Array, ith array  
   for(r=0; r<map_height; r++){ // for each col
       for(c=0; c<map_length; c++) // for each row
          array[r][ (i*map_length) + c ]  = mapsarray[i][r][c] ;    
   }
}
```

<sub>use good variable names instead i,j ,k</sub>

Comment: *but this is not answer to your question*

Comment: but i does not work neither... now it looks like the first row is correct but then they get shifted... but the last array is right again:

Comment: can i publish a screenshot?

Comment: @user2019104 I believe what you shown in you code is correct...you should also bug other part of your code

Comment: above i my output... all '|' identify a new array... so i just try to concatenate 2 arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint to make debugging this easier.  Make the outermost loop iterate through 'n'.  Each `mapsarray[n]` is an input array.  Break out the rest of your code into a function that simply writes the data from the input array into the correct location in the output array.  What you ultimately want is something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_maps; ++i)
{
  concatenate_array(array, mapsarray[n], n);
}
```

With that architecture, you can execute the `concatenate_array` function on each input individually and observe where the data gets written.  This should make it more obvious where your array index arithmetic or loop boundary conditions need to be adjusted.